# Vectorizing / Contrasting a Dataframe with Categorical Variables

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statsmodels

Say I have a dataframe like the following:

```
      A      B
0   bar    one
1   bar  three
2  flux    six
3   bar  three
4   foo   five
5  flux    one
6   foo    two
```

I would like to apply  [**dummy-coding** contrasting](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/webbooks/reg/chapter5/sasreg5.htm) on it so that I get:

```
    A    B
0   0    0
1   0    2
2   1    1
3   0    2
4   2    3
5   1    0
6   2    4
```

(i.e. mapping every unique value to a different integer, per column).

I have tried using scikit-learn's [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html), but I get:

```
> from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer as DV
> vectorizer        = DV( sparse = False )
> dict_to_vectorize = df.T.to_dict().values()
> df_vec            = vectorizer.fit_transform(dict_to_vectorize )
> df_vec
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

This is because scikit-learn's `DictVectorizer` is designed to output one-of-K encoding. What I want is a simple-encoding instead (one column per variable).

How can I do this with scikit-learn and/or pandas? Aside from that, are there any other Python packages that help with general [contrasting methods](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/webbooks/reg/chapter5/sasreg5.htm#SIMPLE)?

Comment: [`.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html#pandas.factorize)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [pd.factorize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html):

```
In [124]: df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
Out[124]: 
   A  B
0  0  0
1  0  1
2  1  2
3  0  1
4  2  3
5  1  0
6  2  4
```

Answer (score 3):

The `patsy` package provides all the contrasts you'd need (and the ability to make more). [1] AFAIK, statsmodels is the only stats package that currently uses patsy's formula framework. [2, 3].

[1] https://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API-reference.html#handling-categorical-data

[2] http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/contrasts.html

[3] http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html

Comment: Thanks! I think `pymc` supports formulas as well: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc/issues/199

Answer (score 2):

Dummy encoding is what you get when you call `DictVectorizer`. The kind of integer encoding you get is actually different:

- `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer` or `DictVectorizer` gives dummy encoding (as `pandas.get_dummies`)
- `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` gives integer categorical encoding (as `pandas.factorize`)